# c#, tcp client does not work as intended (too slow?)

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, autoit

I am a beginner when it comes to networking. Even so, I have only programmed as a hobby. It's about a problem that I can't really explain. I have a packetlogger attached to a game this starts a tcp server. Then I built a TCP client in C# (It is a console application in VisualStudio 2022) with the following code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int PORT_NO = 51615;
        const string SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1";
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(SERVER_IP, PORT_NO);
        const int packetLogger_Recv = 0;
        const int packetLogger_Send = 1;
        NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
        while (true)
        {
            byte[] bytesToRead = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
            int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
            string receivedPacket = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesToRead, 0, bytesRead);
            Console.WriteLine("Receive: " + receivedPacket);
        }
    }
```

Now I think, however, that it would have to put a "Receive:" in front of every line it gets from the server, but that is only very irregular and should not be correct. Maybe someone can explain me the problem and give me a solution. If anyone is interested, it
is the game NosTale

There is also an example but unfortunately only in AutoIT, of which I have unfortunately 0 idea, but with it it works immediately and also super fast. [AutoIT Example][1]
[1]: https://gitlab.com/ImBlackDude/nostale-packetlogger/-/blob/master/PacketLogger_API.au3

The output looks like this:

```
0 cond 1 27511 0 0 131 3
0 mv 3 2188 52 162 8312 11 200 0 0 1 98 0 4 0
0 cond 1 27511 0 0 137387
0 cond 1 27511 0 0 131 3
0 mv 3 2111 17 17 863248 131 24
0 mv 2 2006683 78 151 1010 8
0 cond 1 27511 0 0 13 0 0
0 cond 1 27511 0 0 130
0 cond 1 27511 0 0 130 3005
0 cond 1 27511 0 0 137317
0 cond 1 27511 0 0 13 42 125 24
0 mv 1 27491 75 111 12 3005
0 mv 1 27567 76 148 127 75 148 10
0 su 2 2196 3 2033 0 12 11 514 0 0 1 27 19 0 0
0 cond 1 27511 0 0 1311 0 0 13
Receive: 0 mv 1 27491 70 112 12
0 cond 1 27511 0 0 137525
0 mv 1 27426 37 120 241 116 1
0 cond 1 27511 0 0 133 3
0 cond 1 27511 0 0 137101
Receive: 0 mv 1 27426 35 118 24
0 mv 3 2188 51 162 8312 11 514 0 0 1 3 0 4 0
0 cond 1 27511 0 0 132525
0 mv 3 2181 41 165 850
0 cond 1 27511 0 0 131 3
Receive: 0 dm 3 2053 0
0 cond 1 27511 0 0 1311 0 0 13
Receive: 0 mv 1 27491 63 110 12
0 mv 3 2188 50 162 8312 11 200 0 0 1 98 0 4 0
0 cond 1 27511 0 0 13116 80 10
0 cond 1 27511 0 0 137378
Receive: 0 mv 1 27491 60 108 12
0 cond 1 27511 0 0 137 3
0 cond 1 27511 0 0 137400
0 mv 3 2187 48 162 8381 115 1
0 cond 1 27511 0 0 130 3
0 mv 3 2186 47 163 85115 78 10
0 cond 1 27511 0 0 13 0 0 0 10 0
Receive: 0 mv 1 27491 57 106 12
Receive: 0 mv 1 27426 32 110 24
0 cond 1 27511 0 0 137387
0 eff 1 26955 3951 134 3
0 mv 3 2183 39 156 8312 11 514 0 0 1 15 19 0 0
0 mv 3 2179 28 163 830
0 cond 1 27511 0 0 13 55 104 12
0 mv 3 2107 15 3 8 6512 11 514 0 0 0 0 19 0 0477.4618.4465.-1.4714.4536.4534.4588.4538 24 100 0 2195 4 2 0 51 0 20 108 108 130 CARTEL 28 0 20 0 18 99 4 1 0|0|0 1 10 80 0
0 mv 1 27426 26 102 243 12 8
0 cond 1 27511 0 0 13 0 0
0 cond 1 27511 0 0 1379 114 1
```

Comment: Do you use TCP for any particular reason? Using some higher level library/protocol would likely be easier.

Comment: not really, i thought since the packetlogger.dll creates a tcp server, it would be smart to build a tcp client. (I honestly don't even know if you can add another client with another protocol to listen to it) Which libary or protocol would be easier?

Comment: I am not even sure what your question is? You mix languages, german and english. 
You reference an example, but don't actually provide said example. 

I am not sure why you think a receive needs to be inserted? 

Please follow the guide for minimal reproducable question.

Comment: I have used zeroMq, (see [NetMQ](https://netmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) ), but there are *many* options to chose from. But it probably require you to control both sides of the communication.

Comment: @MortenBork my question is: why is there not always a receive in front of the output? The problem is that I have to process and prepare the packets later, so that I can build a bot that executes certain things ingame based on the packets. The problem is that I can not manipulate all packages, otherwise there would be a receive in front of each line(?) or do I see it wrong. German english mix I have corrected sorry.

Comment: my guess is that there is a cr 0x0d at the start of the receive packet.

Comment: I agree with pm100
There is like a symbol included in the text, that makes a CR-LF for the console. Like \n or \n\r or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I needed to split the string at CR 0x0d ("\r").